# Error "generating static pages" in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Having created a few tutorial projects using `create-react-app`, I recently made the switch to Next.js. Here's what I've done so far:

- Started by executing `create-next-app@latest`.
- Established a `Components` folder within `src/app`.
- Edited the default `page.js` located in `src/app` to include my components. It now renders as follows:

```
<>
  <Header />
  <Main />
  <Footer />
</>
```

- Inside the `Components` folder, I organized subfolders for `Header`, `Main`, `Footer`, and others. Each contains two files i.e.: `Header.js` and `Header.module.css`.

Running the application using `next dev` has been smooth sailing. However, attempting `next build` results in a barrage of errors, starting from:

```
 Generating static pages (0/10)  [=   ]TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/kawaiier/Git/GMG/client/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/Users/kawaiier/Git/GMG/client/.next/server/chunks/942.js:1:4437)
    at Wc (/Users/kawaiier/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/kawaiier/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
```

and extending to:

```
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /_not-found
        /page: /
```

---

In an attempt to resolve this, I consolidated all my components directly into the `pages` folder, restructuring it to look like:

```
- Header.js
- Header.module.css
- Footer.js
- Footer.module.css
...
```

This setup allows the application to run using `next dev`, but unfortunately, the `next build` command still triggers the same set of errors, culminating in:

```
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /Converter
        /Footer
        /Header
        /Main
        /Rates
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /_not-found
        /page: /
```

---

I'm currently at a loss regarding how to successfully build and deploy this project. Any advice or suggestions on resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere inside your static pages that are being built is an error preventing a successful build.

```
interface SomeType {
  someKey: { someProp: "foo" };
}

export default function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const value = useContext<SomeType>(MyContext);
  // the below line will cause an error because the store's default 
  // state is null on the server
  if (value.someKey.someProp === "bar") return <></>;
  return <></>
}
```

Judging by the error above I strongly suspect somewhere may be a `useContext` that tries to access a property before the store has been populated.